# error en laravel . error en consola 401 (Unauthorized) al hacer petición

Tags: laravel, reactjs, axios, cabeceras-http

tengo una consulta , paso a detallar lo mas que pueda para poder tener una ayuda:
Estoy haciendo un proyecto con backend en laravel y en frontend con react. En laravel, estoy usando laravel sanctum. Actualmente tengo correcto el login y el registro. Tuve grandes inconvenientes con el logout porque no me daba el permiso. Pero eso lo implementé de otra manera pero cuando yo quiero hacer el logout, lo que quiero es que me actualice el valor que tengo en la base de datos de los colores del navbar para que, cuando el usuario se loguee, ponga el color que se eligió.

Yo implemente el siguiente codigo en el archivo .jsx:

```
const logout = (e)=>{
   e.preventDefault();
   //obtengo el valor del token 
   let cookie = document.cookie;
   let valorCookie = cookie.split('=');
   let token = valorCookie[1];
   console.log(token);
   //hago los headers para el encabezado
   const headers = {
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json', // Tipo de contenido que estás enviando
   };
   console.log(headers);
   //info para enviar por post
   let usuario = localStorage.getItem('auth_usuario');
   let usuarioObjeto = JSON.parse(usuario);
   let id = usuarioObjeto.id;
   const data = {
      id: id,
      color: localStorage.getItem('color'),
   }
   console.log(data)
   axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/personalizacion', data, { headers })
      .then(response => {
         // Maneja la respuesta aquí
         console.log('Respuesta:', response.data);
         //ELIMINACION DE TODO LO QUE HAY EN EL LOCALSTORAGE
         localStorage.removeItem('auth_token');
         localStorage.removeItem('color');
         localStorage.removeItem('auth_usuario');
         localStorage.removeItem('nombre');
         // Llamar a la función para borrar una cookie específica
         borrarCookie("XSRF-TOKEN");
         navigate('/');
       })
       .catch(error => {
          // Maneja errores aquí
          console.error('Error:', error);
       });
    }
```

en las ruta api.php tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->group(function(){
   Route::post('/personalizacion', [UserController::class, 'cambioColor']);
});
```

la funcion en el controlador UserController es el siguiente:

```
public function cambioColor(Request $request){
   try {
      $usuario = User::find($request->id);
      if (!$usuario) {
         return response()->json(['mensaje' => 'Usuario no encontrado'], 404);
      }
      $usuario->color = $request->color;
      $usuario->save();
      return response()->json(['mensaje' => 'Color de usuario actualizado correctamente'], 200);
   } catch (\Exception $e) {
      return response()->json(['mensaje' => 'Error al actualizar el color del usuario'], 500);
   }
```

en el `.env`(tuve varios errores al querer poner `SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost:5173` y `SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost` porque he visto que hay que ponerlo pero cuando lo hago, me dejan de funcionar las otras funcionalidades)
quiero saber cual podria ser el error y ademas,uds que pueden tener mas experiencia que yo, me digan como podría yo saber los valores que obtengo en la funcion de cambioColor porque no se como podría saber los valores de las variables y asi ver que tal vez el problema es este codigo.

Lo que yo necesito es que al enviar la peticion http, me realice la actualizacion en la base de datos del valor 'color' del usuario enviado

Gracias

Comment: Desconozco Laravel, pero el error hace referencia a que no tienes permisos para usar ese endpoint. Probaste mediante Postman?? Y si es así, te sale el mismo error 401?

Comment: No es más fácil que el valor se guarde en la base de datos mientras el usuario está logeado? Si no hay una sesión, se ocupa un valor por defecto para el color del navbar.

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera si, yo no uso postman pero uso thunderclient y sale todo bien , el problema es cuando lo uso en el front

Comment: @Jacobo trate de hacerlo en la pagina que tengo para hacer el cambio de color pero me salia el mismo error, además, no queria que se hicieran tantas peticiones por el cambio de color, en cambio cuando cierra sesion, es mas probable que el color que estuvo usando hasta ese entonces sea el elegido. Por eso se implementó asi

Comment: Me refiero a que si no hay ninguna sesión. No tendría porque actualizarse ningún color. Si no hay sesión se usa un color distinto. Simplemente haces el check de la sesión desde el archivo blade.

Comment: Pues veo que el middleware de la ruta hacia la api esta con auth y tienes un localStorage.removeItem... osea eliminas el permiso a esa instancia en el momento de la llamada, en otras palabras te estas pisando la cola, usa un metodo para el cambio de color y otro para verificar si el usuario esta logueado o revisa bien lo que tienes en las rutas puede que necesites una ruta sin middleware para poder loguear y que te redireccione bien.
falta el detalle de las rutas para poder ver que hace el codigo si no tienes permisos